# Does Windows 7 MKLink make a copy of the linked file?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

Assume I make a softlink (symbolic link or junction) to a 50GB directory,
it appears as if the "shortcut" folder is as same as target folder.

Will Windows use 50GB more for the "shortcut" folder?

Comment: I have no idea what I just read, could you rephrase that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, softlinks does not consume additional storage